# genetic programming for trading: How to represent chromosomes

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I am working on a genetic algorithm in python that can be used for trading. The principe is simple if you are familiar with evolutionary algorithms:
The genes represent trading strategies: To be more specific, each gene is a tree of this form:
[image: gene description]

this can be interpreted as a boolean value like this:

If:

- the **average** of the **50** last stock values is **less** the
  actual **price**
- **and** the **min** of the **6** last stock values is **less** the actual **price**. 
  then answer *True**, else **False**

If the answer is True, then send a BUY signal, and SELL signal otherwise.

This is an example of how I represent a tree like this in python:

```
class BinaryRule:
def __init__(self, child1, child2):
    self.child1 = child1
    self.child2 = child2


class LessThan(BinaryRule):
    name = '<'

    def eval(self):
        return self.child1.eval() < self.child2.eval()

# Here there is the definition of the other classes

# and then I create the tree
   tree = rules.LessThan(     
                    rules.Max( rules.Float(1) ),                 
                      rules.SMA( rules.Float(15) ),
                      )
   print tree.eval() # True or false
```

The problem is that I can't think of good technique for the **crossover** and the **mutation** operators. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you representing these at present?

Comment: You are... leaving out some pretty key pieces of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your operators should be safely interchangeable - should all accept the same input-types and return the same output-type (most likely float).

Not necessary but a good idea (by way of neural networks): use differentiable operator-functions - ie instead of returning YES or NO, return "degree-of-yes-ness". This provides more graduated feedback on improvements to your expression. It can also be useful to give each operator a setpoint control value to tweak its behavior.

A mutation operator can change an operator's type or setpoint; a crossover operation usually swaps sub-trees.

A fairly standard binary tree representation is in the form of a list like [head, left, right, left-left, left-right, right-left, right-right, left-left-left, ...]. The nice thing is that, given the index of any node, you can immediately calculate the parent, left-child, and right-child indices; a downside is that it can waste a lot of space if you have a sparse tree structure. Also, properly copying subtrees should be done via a recursive function, not a simple slice-and-splice as @Slater shows above.

Answer (score 1):

This is not typically the way that genetic algorithms are represented, and I personally don't feel that a genetic algorithm is the right approach for this, but nonetheless this is certainly possible.

Assuming you just want to interact with this specific set of variables, you have a small set of potential values:

```
boolean = "and"
comparator = "<"
```

etc...

this means you can easily represent these as a flat list:

```
chromosome = ["and", "<", ...]
```

crossover is then just mixing two chromosomes at some specific split point:

```
def crossover(cr1, cr2):
    split_point = random.randint(1, len(cr1))
    return [cr1[:split_point] + cr2[split_point:]], [cr2[:split_point] + cr1[split_point:]]
```

mutation then is also relatively trivial, just changing a number at random, switching the boolean operator, etc... I'll leave that one as an exercise to the reader though.

Comment: This assumes a linear flow of instructions rather than a tree.

Comment: @HughBothwell It does not. This is simply casting a defined tree structure to a list with a definite order of application to that tree for crossover. The chromosome layout here is independent of the tree itself, and OP did not imply they wanted to actually edit the structure of the tree. If they do so I will change this answer.